# Upgraded apache to 2.4 wont load pages

Tags: 12.04, apache2.4

I need help, I upgraded apache to 2.4 and now it only shows

> Index of /

You can see it here http://marketplace.aviworlds.us
it worked before but not now how do i fix this? also nothing shows up in the log files either.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin quill.littlefeather@localhost
  ServerName  marketplace.aviworlds.us
  ServerAlias marketplace.aviworlds.us

  DocumentRoot /var/store
  DirectoryIndex index.php



  <Directory /var/store>
        Options -ExecCGI    
    AllowOverride all
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Maybe it's your browser, the page works fine.

Comment: You need to rename the virtual host config files so they end with a `.conf` extension. You need to do that in both, `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` and `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`. You also probably need to disable the `000-default.conf` virtual host.

Answer (score 0):

Under `<Directory>` you now have to add `Require all granted` directive

```
<Directory /var/store>
   Options -ExecCGI    
   AllowOverride all
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then reload apache conf or restart

Comment: I tried that just now and still changed nothing.